# Taglist 'jump-to-label' working incorrectly

Tags: plugins, latex, vim, taglist

I am trying to get my taglist plugin to work correctly. I'm specifically trying to get it to work correctly with tex files and the latex-suite plugin, although the behavior exists for other files.

Installation instructions were followed. I have the latest version of Exuberant ctags and taglist installed. When I opened my taglist window, it looks like all the sections, labels, and references were correctly found.

My problem: I cannot jump to the tags shown in the taglist window. Hitting 'enter' does nothing.

If access the functionality through the 'Tags' drop down menu, it seems like taglist is adding part of the label text before the call. For example if I have a section called

```
\section{Experimental Observables},
```

taglist will issue the command

```
bservables :call <SNR>25_Tlist_Menu_Jump_To_Tag(3)
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!